# I have a webpage with two bundles. Webpack will not instantiate a jquery ui item on the second bundle

Tags: jquery, webpack

I have a script, *myCommon.php*, in a directory: *dist/commontest*. It is simply a div element with text and a script which applies css:

```js
$('#module1').css('margin-left', '24px');
```

Note that to procure the correct bundle when *myCommon.php* is included on a page, the path for the script is:

```html
<script src="../commontest/bundle.js"></script>
```

My webpage, *test.php*, is a second php file (in directory: *dist/test*) which contains an input tag for a jquery ui spinner:

```html
<input class="spinner" />
```

The webpage 'requires' *myCommon.php*. The webpage has its own separate script which instantiates the spinner:

```js
$(".spinner").spinner({
    min: 1,
    max: 50
});
```

Webpack builds both bundles and places them in the correct *dist/* directories. In the test case outlined above, the ui item will not instantiate:
`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).spinner is not a function`
If I move the spinner js to the script for myCommon.php, it **will** instantiate correctly.
webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'commontest': './src/test/module1.js',
    'test': './src/test/module2.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './dist/[name]/bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ["style-loader","css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
        loader:"file-loader",
        options:{
          name:'[name].[ext]',
          outputPath:'../assets/images/'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    /* Use the ProvidePlugin constructor to inject jquery implicit globals */
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery'",
        "window.$": "jquery"
    })
  ],
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

What am I missing?